# How to update libreoffice 6.3 to 6.4 via terminal

Tags: libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS now I update my LibreOffice by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` command but I update to 6.3 only.
Any other way to update LibreOffice 6.4 via terminal?

Comment: The fact that you still get 6.3 is because 6.4 is not yet available via [libreoffice ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). It will be included in few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6.4 is not in the PPA yet. If you really want it then:

- Download the archive with the installation packages (.deb) from the LibreOffice web site (https://www.libreoffice.org/download, in "Choose you operating system" select "Linux (64-bit) (deb)", then Download)
- Extract the file you've just downloaded and install the .deb packages you get:

```
$ tar -xf LibreOffice_*_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
$ cd LibreOffice_*_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEPS
$ sudo dpkg --install *.deb
```

If there is an error about missing packages, issue a

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

to install missing references or refer to readmes/README_en-US for further help.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. I downloaded it from LibreOffice site extract and installed.

Comment: Great, mark my post as answer if you like, so that it your question won't show up as unanswered when people look for it.